# Windows update change download location

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, windows-update

Is there a way to change the download path of windows updates?

(I want to protect my SSDs from unnecessary writes.)

Edit:

I read a lot of articles about SSD in the last 6 months, and I came to the conclusion, that it is not necessary to protect the SSD this way from the writes. A modern SSD withstands at least 500TB write during it's lifetime, so these few GBs of data does not really matter. http://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead/3

Comment: By the time your SSD is out of writes, it will be so woefully obsolete it won't matter.  The little dust from Windows Update will do nothing to appreciably change its lifespan.

Comment: @insta Thanks, you might be right, but I'll try it. Maybe that one or two days of lifetime will matter, who knows...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but what about a symlink?

`net stop wuauserv
mklink /j c:\windows\softwaredistribution d:\other\desired\location
net start wuauserv`

Comment: Good idea, take a look: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jeffloucks/2010/09/19/redirecting-updates-and-the-software-distribution-folder-using-junction-to-another-hard-drive/

Comment: `Junction` predates `mklink`. I think both are good but in this case the native solution is probably preferred (assuming it works, of course.)

Comment: @meatspace Thanks! I'll try it. Why do I need to stop windows update service? I configured it to download only when I say to do so, so I guess that part is not necessary. I'll try that too. :-)

Comment: @meatspace It works perfectly. You have to set manual update (you don't have to stop the service, just be sure it is not using the folder), move the folder to the different drive and set the symlink. After that it is even possible to detach that drive. I prefer the native solutions either.

Answer (score 10):

The updates are **automatically** downloaded to the `WINDOWS\Software Distribution\Download` subfolder.
They are then unpacked to the drive which has the most free space available and installed from there.
The contents of the Download subfolder are periodically flushed.

**There's no way to redirect where the updates are downloaded to due to Security concerns.**

---

After reading a post of [meatspace](https://superuser.com/users/402836/meatspace) I have found [this one](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jeffloucks/2010/09/19/redirecting-updates-and-the-software-distribution-folder-using-junction-to-another-hard-drive/):

- `Start>Run`
- type `cmd` and press enter
- type `net stop wuauserv` and press enter
- type `rename c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution softwaredistribution.oldand` press enter

Creating a symbolic link using [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) (Download)

In this example the software distribution folder will be redirected from `C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution` to the `D:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution`

- Creating the Junction

To create the target directory from the command prompt

```
C:\md D:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution
```

To create the Junction

```
C:\junction C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution “D:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution”
```

- Restart the Windows Update Service
- type `net start wuauserv` and press enter

Comment: This is a nice step-by-step, but why not just use `mklink /D` ?

Comment: This is the answer of @meatspace and has been accepted.